# System.IO.File.ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED=5

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando con "File.Exists", y mientras entro al DEBUG observe ciertos eventos que no comprendo.

Alguien tiene una idea de que puede tratar, pese al mensaje, logra leer las carpetas y archivos sin inconvenientes.

Les cuento que en esta pequeña aplicación, estoy realizando validación, si existe un archivo en cierta ruta, lamentablemente demora bastante por que hay unas 850000 imágenes .TIF y el base de datos unos 870000 registros(nombre_imagen).

[image: Mensaje que aparece dentro del DEBUG]

Comment: Hola, verificaste que la aplicacion tenga permiso a la carpeta donde consulta las imagenes? O si la carpeta tiene deshabilitada la seguridad? Si es asi, entonces verifica el pool de conexion que estas utilizando en IIS y verifica que estas con las credenciales necesarias para realizar esa accion

Comment: Hola **@FranciscoVelásquez**, esta carpeta de imágenes se encuentra en una de las particiones de mi disco duro,tiene todos los permisos, pero igual me aparece el mensaje. Respecto a IIS, no comprendo que tiene que ver eso?? Mi aplicación esta en Windows Forms C#.

Comment: Disculpa, crei que era una aplicacion web... En todo sentido, no creo que sea cuestion de permiso ya que al parecer leer otros archivos y tu sistema funciona pero porque utilizas un try catch.. En todo caso tu error mas bien esta en ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, por lo que te sugiero, corras el codigo nuevamente pero coloques un stop en esa parte(seria mas rapido en el catch Exception) y leas el contenido de "ruta_imagen", pueda que vaya vacio ese campo o con algun caracter que este haciendo falle File.Exist

Answer (score -1):

Posiblemente el path este mal armado.

1. Captura el valor de ruta_imagen y pegala en el explorador de carpetas para corroborar que este bien escrito
2. Revisa que el path no tenga mas de 256 caracteres https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation. Puede que se te pase la cantidad porque te pone muchos `\..\..\..`, es algo que suele pasar en Windows
3. Agrega un try/catch wrapeando el `if(!File.Exists(...)` para capturar el verdadero error y obtener tb los InnerException y los mensajes de error un poco mas descriptivos.
   Te sugiero siempre agregues el try/catch porque no sabes a futuro si el usuario que le des esa app va a tener permisos o si por algún motivo la empresa decide pasar el path a un disco de red donde los permisos los maneja el equipo de seguridad. De esta forma no explotara la aplicación y podrás mostrar un mensaje adecuado.